# create vba code in ms access to effect each combo box on a form globally instead of creating code for each individual cbo box.

Tags: ms-access

I have a form in ms access with many combo boxes.  I want to see the dropdown options when the cb has the focus.  I can do this individually using me.cboboxname.dropdown.  instead of doing this individually on all cbo boxes can i create a module or code that will do this for each cbo box each time it has focus?

Answer (score 2):

Using classes, you can assign event handlers to all your combo boxes in a single form.

In a separate class module:

Class name: **Class1**

```
Public WithEvents cmb As Access.ComboBox

Private Sub cmb_GotFocus()
    cmb.DropDown
End Sub
```

In the form class module:

```
Private collEventHandlers As Collection

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Set collEventHandlers = New Collection
    Dim ctl As Access.Control
    Dim eventHandler As Class1
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf ctl Is Access.ComboBox Then
            Set eventHandler = New Class1
            Set eventHandler.cmb = ctl
            colleventHanlers.Add eventHandler
            ctl.OnGotFocus = "[Event Procedure]"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I had to add then after If TypeOf ctl Is Access.ComboBox Then I rcvd the following error:  Microsoft Access cannot find the object 'Event Handler'

Comment: You must've deviated from my code somewhere. Note that you must _first_ create the  class module and add the code to that, before adding the code to the form module, else it won't compile.

Comment: Hello, I am still trying to get this. I have followed your code exactly and am getting the error:  "Microsoft Access cannot find the object 'Event Handler.'  If 'Event Handler' is a new macro or macro group, make sure you have saved it and that you have typed its name correctly. the problem appears to be in line ctl.OnGotFocus = "[Event Handler]"  is this supposed to be calling the private sub cmb_GotFocus()? should I be putting different text in the brackets other than Event Handler ? I am sure it is something ignorant I am doing but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Try the current edit, sorry, should've been event procedure

Comment: So after adding event procedure I am not getting the error anymore however it doesn't ever go to the class1 module code.  When I type the last line in the if statement ctl. I do not get ongotfocus as an option in the auto options that appear but it does capitalize it when I go out of that line not sure if that is the problem?

Comment: Have you declared collEventHandlers at the top of the form module (so not inside the sub)? It's usual intellisense does not work for all proporties there, since it might also be a different kind of control that doesn't support that property

Comment: on the form module at top is option compare database then private colleventhandlers as collection, then a line all the way across then private sub form_load() then the rest of code per your instructions.  When the form loads it runs through the code for all the controls including the if code for all the combo boxes I have in the form a total of 12. finally the code ends and the form opens but when I put focus on any of the comboboxes nothing happens, it does not jump to the code in the class1 module like it should, any idea why not?  this could be very powerful for many uses!

Comment: Always add option explicit at the top of your modules. Have you created the separate class module per my instructions?

Comment: Yes I created the Class1 module in the class modules folder and entered the code Public WithEvents cmb As Access.ComboBox

Private Sub cmb_GotFocus()
    cmb.DropDown
End Sub
plus the code in the form module.  It seems something is missing possibly in the if statement, after opening the form running through the code I look at the form in design view and each of the combo boxes have [Event Procedure] showing in the event tab of the property sheet in the On Got Focus event.  When I go in to that event in vb code there is private sub abc_GotFocus() a blank line and then End Sub,  No code crt

Comment: Also I did not have option explicit in either of the 2 sets of code but I did add them after option compare database at the top and re loaded the form but it did not do anything.

Comment: Oh, very sorry, indeed missed a line in that if: `collEventHandlers.Add eventHandler`, anywhere but the first line is ok.

Comment: Beautiful, this works perfectly, I updated and tested the code.  With the persistent help of Erik von Asmuth and a bit of a struggle we were able to come up with some fairly short and straightforward code that works very effectively to handle collectively similar objects as opposed to writing individual code for each object.  Also, this can be modified to work with other types of similar objects on a form and perform other actions to the objects as needed.   Very powerful and time saving.